# Add descending indexes in MySQL 8.0 via peewee migrate

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I am working on a MySQL database. I first create a table by peewee, then insert all records, and the final step is creating indexes for columns. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549667/retroactively-create-indexes-with-peewee), I know I can use peewee migrate to create index after the table has been created.

For example, let's say I have a table as below

```
import peewee as pw
import playhouse.migrate

db = pw.MySQLDatabase(...)
migrator = playhouse.migrate.MySQLMigrator(db)

class User(pw.Model):
    username = pw.CharField()
    userval = pw.FloatField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

db.create_tables([User])
# insert all records
...

# add index
with db.atomic():
    playhouse.migrate.migrate(
        migrator.add_index('User', ('userval',)),
    )
```

I can successfully create the index for this single column "userval", but my question is how to create a [**descending index**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html) for this column? Since the `add_index` only accepts strings, I can't use `User.userval.desc()`, then how to pass the keyword `DESC` to the migrator?

Or there is actually no way to create the descending index via peewee, and I have to login into MySQL, and then create the index by

```
CREATE INDEX userval_index ON User (userval DESC)
```

Comment: Based on [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html), MySQL 8.0 supports Descending Indexes. A descending index can be scanned in forward order, which is more efficient. And descending indexes also make it possible for the optimizer to use multiple-column indexes. In my suitation, the data retrieving results always need to be ordered by `col1 ASC, col2 DESC`, so I think a multi-column index with descending on `col2` may help to speed up data retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
with db.atomic():
    playhouse.migrate.migrate(
        migrator.add_index('User', ('userval DESC',)),
    )
```

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't work and raised an error `peewee.OperationalError: (1072, "Key column 'userval DESC' doesn't exist in table")`. It seems peewee treats the string `userval DESC` as a column name